# Stuck on Simple Math Algorithm

Tags: php, math

I can't remember what this is called in math, it's not powers though. I'm validating a consecutive order of numbers. They always start at 1 and can go to 3. I really have 3 conditions only.

So my solution was:

```
$sum = array_sum($group);
count: 1 = (Result) 1
count: 2 = (Result) 3 (1 + 2)
count: 3 = (Result) 6 (1 + 2 + 3)
```

However, I would like to trim the fat of these 3 if statements into something simpler, can you help me with that math algorithm?

```
    $winnerCount = [
        [1, 3]
    ];

    foreach ($winnerCount as $_key => $_group)
    {
        $winnerTotal = count($_group);
        $sum = array_sum($winnerCount[$_key]);

        if ($winnerTotal == 1 && $sum != 1) {
            $error = true;
        }
        if ($winnerTotal == 2 && $sum != 3) {
            $error = true;
        }
        if ($winnerTotal == 3 && $sum != 6) {
            $error = true;
        }

        echo $sum;
    }
```

I do reckon I need some coffee this fine afternoon.

I suppose I could do something kinda like this:

```
$result = [
    1 => 1,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 6
];

if ($winnerTotal != $result[$winnerTotal]) {
    $error = true
}
```

Comment: FYK, those are [triangular numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) ^^.

Comment: `$triangleNumber = array_sum(range(1,12));` to get the 12th triangular number

Comment: Wow that's a very awesome way Mark, make that an answer that's so smart.

Comment: Given his small sample size, couldn't this also be a factorial? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial

Comment: Thats the word I was looking for @DigitalChris that I thought it was

Comment: The answer depends on what your value for 4 is :p if it is `(1+2+3+4)` then yes this is a triangle number. If `(1*2*3*4)` it's factorial.

Comment: 4 would hopefully be: (1 + 2 + 3 + 4) = 10

Comment: @DigitalChris The second one does not work out, should be 3, but `2! == 2`

Comment: @jeroen DOH right you are

Comment: Reason for downvoting? I demand an explanation! It was a valid question D;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nth triangular number is given by the formula

```
g(n) = n(n+1)/2
```

Comment: Wow thats a sweet formula

Answer (score 2):

formula : **n = n(n+1)/2**

therefore you could try the followong in your loop :

```
if($winnerTotal != $winnerTotal ($winnerTotal + 1 ) / 2){
    $error = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a loop like this :

```
function sumNum($num){
    $sum = 0 ;
    for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){
        $sum += $i;
    }
    return $sum;
}
$sum = sumNum($count);
```

OR most simple way :

```
$sum = ($count*($count+1))/2;
```